# Get the identifier of a Windows error code

Tags: c++, winapi

In a program I'm developing I need to gather information about runtime errors. Currently, I am able to gather all the information I need, including the message via `FormatMessage`, but the identifier of the error (for example, `ERROR_SUCCESS`). I know that when the application is compiled these identifiers are not actually present in the binaries.

Is there a function in the Windows API which can retrieve these identifiers or do I need to store them with my application?

Comment: To my knowledge, such an API does not exist. You will have to maintain a mapping in your application. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681381.aspx) is the reference list. It's huge. Good luck.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I'll see if I get lucky and someone knows one. I've already started writing a script to make the mapping automatically but I'd rather not use it

Comment: Why would you need these when you have the integer value and the `FormatMessage` string?

Comment: @chris: I am making an application that displays information about a code the user enters, so I would like to be able to show the identifier along with the other information I have gathered

Comment: @InsideOutCloud, Ah, I personally don't know of any way to do that (reverse macros anyone?), so a map would probably be your best bet. Not worth the effort imo.

Comment: @InsideOutCloud: Oh, just like the [Microsoft Exchange Server Error Code Look-up](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=985) utility?

Comment: @InsideOutCloud: Also remember that a error code values are domain specific so the same code can be used by hundreds of different constants.

Comment: @Deanna: Kind of like that but with a better interface. I have definitely found out that codes can repeat while making my map file. Shouldn't be a problem though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ERROR_SUCCESS` itself is just a constant. I haven't found a way to go from number -> constant identifier.

You could scan `WinError.h` with [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) and create some kind of table for your application.

Comment: I'll give this a shot and report back

Comment: MS already have a [utility](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=985) that does this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice example of how you can get the ErrorCode and how to translate it to a more readable message on MSDN.

No need to copy that over, its quite plain:

[Retrieving the last error code and message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680582%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: I already have the message, I just need the identifer (eg. `ERROR_SUCCESS`)

Comment: okay. the identifier is just a define, i.e. the number of the error. and you want the name of that define? i.e. #define ERROR_SUCCESS 0, you want to get ERROR_SUCCESS for output?

Comment: Pretty much. I know that the pre-processor removes `ERROR_SUCCESS` and replaces it with the value, which makes me believe I will indeed need to make a map.

Comment: yes, i do not believe you can get that identifier in any way, because the preprocessor will replace them, therefore it is no longer available after preprocessor made his job. but you can derive your own from winerror.h, with some macros it is not that big thing. is that a possible answer for you?